# How to open 2 URLs at the same time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am trying to figure out a way to open both URLs at the same time to save time.
As yu can see here if 10.10.10.2 is reachable then the programm shuts down and if 192.168.100.5 is reachable then the programm continue.
Sorry for this amateur question guys I am very new to programming hence go easy on me.
My solution below takes a lot of time because it happens one after the other.
I am writing a small checking tool in python to see if the devices have the correct IP address. so the devices with 10.10.10.2 is faulty and this is the correct IP address 192.168.100.5.
There are over 8000 devices to test hence waiting 10 seconds for each device takes too much time.
Do you guys know of any other method to call 2 different URLs at the same time.
I have read about threading but i really do not know how to apply that here if someone could show me an example of how it could be done that would be much appreciated.
A quick summary of what it should be like:
call both URLs at the same time, the first url to respond decides if the python programm will continue or not.
if 10.10.10.2 is reachable programm shuts down and if 192.168.100.5 is reachable then the programm continues.

Code examples could be very helpful guys.

```
try:
    preflash = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.10.10.2", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", preflash, "FAIL")  
    sys.exit(0)
    
except urllib.error.URLError:
    correct = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", correct)
    print("IP address: 192.168.100.5 is reachable")
```

Comment: had you try to create 2 threads ?

Comment: AIOHTTP module can help you, it allows you to make aysnc and await calls concurrently so call 1 is placed then while waiting for the response call 2 is placed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aiohttp with asyncio.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def download_file(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        assert response.status == 200
        # For large files use response.content.read(chunk_size) instead.
        return url, await response.read()


async def download_multiple(session: aiohttp.ClientSession):
          urls = (
              'https://stackoverflow.com/',
              'http://python.org',
          )
          download_futures = [download_file(session, url) for url in urls]
          print('Results')
          done, pending = await asyncio.wait(download_futures, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
          for task in done:
              print(task.result())
          print("unfinished:", len(pending))
          return [p.result()[0] for p in done]

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      result = await download_multiple(session)
      print('finished:', result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

You can play now with done and pending, done contains the first url that finished, pending the others.

main() is a coroutine, run by asyncio.run(). main() uses aiohttp to manage async requests and awaits for download_multiple. download_multiple create a list of futures (awaitable objects) and then use asyncio.wait to "run" them. The policy here is to return when the first one returns. asyncio.wait returns two lists of tasks, done (finished ones) and pending (not finished). Then the first is in done, and the others in pending.